# Use DateTime inputs to filter linq in MVC controller and return to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, telerik-mvc

Can anyone help me get started using two DateTime inputs in an asp.net MVC view to filter a LINQ to Entities query in my controller and return the resulting data through a viewmodel to the view?

Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
    public ActionResult Appointments(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime stopDate = DateTime.Today;

        if(formCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            startDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["datePickerStart"].ToString());
            stopDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["datePickerStop"].ToString());
        }

        using (var db = new SalonContext())
        {
            var homeSalon = GetHomeSalonId();
            var appointments = db.Appointments.Include(c => c.Salon).Include(c => c.Treatment).Include(c => c.Customer).Where(c => c.SalonId == homeSalon).ToList();
            var reportAppointments = appointments.Where(d => d.Start >= startDate && d.Start <= stopDate).Select(
                report => new AppointmentReportViewModel()
                {
                    AppointmentID = report.AppointmentId,
                    AppointmentTime = report.Start,
                    Cancelled = report.Cancelled,
                    Completed = report.Completed,
                    CustomerName = report.Customer.Title + " " + report.Customer.FirstName + " " + report.Customer.Surname,
                    Price = report.Price,
                    Stylist = report.Stylist.Title + " " + report.Stylist.FirstName + " " + report.Stylist.Surname,
                    Treatment = report.Treatment.Name
                }).ToList();

            return View(reportAppointments);
        }
    }
```

And here's the view

```
@model IList<MySalonOrganiser.Models.AppointmentReportViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Appointments";
}

<h2>Appointments</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Appointments", "Report"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div>
       <div style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 180px">
           <span style="margin-right:20px;">Start Date</span>
           @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("datepickerStart")
              .Value(DateTime.Today)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
           )
       </div>
       <div style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 180px">
           <span style="margin-right:20px;">Stop Date</span>
           @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("datepickerStop")
              .Value(DateTime.Today)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
           )
       </div>

        <input type="Submit" value="Filter Report Dates" />
    </div>
}

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Customer Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Appointment Time
            </th>
            <th>
                Treatment
            </th>
            <th>
                Stylist
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Completed
            </th>
            <th>
                Cancelled
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].CustomerName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].AppointmentTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].Treatment)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].Stylist)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].Completed)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].Cancelled)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see I am trying to use the Telerik DatePicker control.

However, the model in the view is IList so should I use ViewBag to send and receive this stuff or how would I get the datetime into the collection?

Many thanks.

Jason.

Comment: What are yo struggling to do? Getting the DateTime field from view to controller or vice versa?

Comment: Both really, but from the view to the controller first. I will worry about from the controller to the view later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DatePicker for

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.FlightStartDate)
 .HtmlAttributes( new {id="startDate", style = "width:252px;"}))
```

On form submit, the DatePicker field will bind to the FlightStartDate property of my model.

And then in controller if you want to populate the field on page render.

```
    MyModelClass model = new MyModelClass();
    model.FlightStartDate = DateTime.Now();

    return View(model);
```

Here's how you could use Tuple for multiple Models.

```
         ViewModel model1 = new ViewModel();
         IList<Model2> model2 = new IList<Model2>();
          var tuple = new Tuple<ViewModel, IList<Model2>(model1, model2);
```

Then in your View

```
@model Tuple<ViewModel, IList<Model2>
```

Then your DatePickerFor would become

`@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.Item1.FlightStartDate)`

Comment: I already have a model that is a collection (IList).Are you saying I can send two models, or extend my model to include this other field? Since I currently send a collection of models, how do you suggest I send this single datetime values?

Comment: Fill the DateTime property in your LinQ statement, and even though it is a list, it should still populate the field with 1 value.

Comment: So, add a start and end time to the view model (in each record) and bind to that?

Comment: Yea, if it won't let you bind since it is a list, you can try using tuple, which will allow you to define multiple models in a view. I'm not sure of the exact syntax so your gonna have to look around. Once your tuple is set up, you can have a list of your 1 model and then just a single Model instance. Your DatePickerFor would look something like `Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.Model1.StartDate)`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118310/ado-net-mvc3-tuple-using-in-model-and-single-views

Answer (score 0):

```
//--Below code to filter list based on from and to Date
// ---From Date 
        <code>
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate))
            {
                DemoList = DemoList.FindAll(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.DemoRegistrationDate).Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).Date);
            }
        </code>

// ---To Date 
       <code>
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
            {
                DemoList = DemoList.FindAll(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.DemoRegistrationDate).Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(toDate).Date);
            }
        </code>
```